# How can I find and/or copy Manage Service settings for a service in Central Admin from one server to another?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, central-administration, service-application

I am trying to figure out the specifics of Managed Metadata Web Service on our Production server to reproduce the same settings in our development server.

I was wondering if there might be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move/copy Managed Metadata Service from one farm to another, you should do the following:

- First, it's recommended to stop the managed metadata service before move using PowerShell.

  ```
   Get-SPServiceInstance
   Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity <ServiceGUID>
  ```
- Get the service database by running the below command

  ```
  Get-SPDatabase | Where {$_.Type -like "*MetadataWebService*"} | Select Name
  ```
- In your production, open SQL server, perform a database backup for the Managed Metadata service database, to do that check [Back Up and Restore of SQL Server Databases.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512214&clcid=0x409) or you can use [Database Detach and Attach (SQL Server)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=512211&clcid=0x409) as the following:

  - Right click on database > de-attach.
  - locate the .mdf, .ndf, and .ldf files for Managed Metadata database files and paste it to your dev farm.
- In production, attach the database again.
- Start the service instance again.

  ```
  Start-SPServiceInstance -Identity <ServiceGUID>
  ```
- In your development env, Perform a attach to the database files or restore the database backup based on your selected backup and restore method.
- Now Point the Managed Metadata service application to a new database server by using Windows PowerShell

  ```
   $app = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "<ServiceApplicationName>"
   Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity $app -DatabaseName "<DbName>"
  ```

**Note:**

For performing the move operations, you must have the following permissions:

- A member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
- A member of the Administrators group on the local server
- Have the `Securityadmin` fixed server role on the SQL Server instance.
- Have the `db_owner` fixed database role for all of the databases that you are moving.

For more details check [Move the Managed Metadata Service service application databases in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729801.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I will have to try this after hours. I will write back then after I have done it to let you know if it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Take your time, and don't hesitate to inform me in case you need any further clarification

Comment: Thank you. I think I might not be able to get to this until next week.